# Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3000,

Tags: .net-5, azure-container-registry

I created a .NET 5 ASP.NET web application with a Dockerfile below.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["./TestNET5"]
```

I added the variables PORT and WEBSITES_PORT with values 3000 in the Configuration settings of the Azure Web App and I also added `-e environment=Production -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` but I am still getting the error below.

`Container xxx didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 3000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.`

Is there I'm missing here? I already checked several articles but I couldn't seem to find a solution.

Comment: Azure web app only support http 80 and https 443 port.

Comment: Even port 80 doesn't work. Setting the WEBSITES_PORT and PORT to 80 in Azure doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

If all the things have been done as you said, then the possible reason is that your image does not work well.

Below I will list all the things you have to do to deploy your application image to Azure App Service:

1. make sure the image can work well locally;
2. set the environment variable `WEBSITES_PORT` if the port the container exposed is not 80 or 443, here its value is 3000;
3. set the environment variables for the docker registry to authenticate if it's private, for example, if you push the image to ACR.

Comment: How do I make it work locally if my local operating system is Windows? I'm new to containers so apologies for my questions.

Comment: @JoshMonreal You can use the [Docker Desktop for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

Comment: Hi Charles, when I tried to pull the image from ACR I got an error saying that the image is only compatible with the Linux OS.

Comment: @JoshMonreal You can change the supported OS for the image. Change the configuration of the Docker Desktop.

Comment: How would you do step 3 of this answer?